# Dynamically populated multiselect list is not showing items

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-multiselect

I am am trying to create a multi select dropdown list with checkboxes dynamically using ASP.Net MVC5. For that I am using bootstrap-multiselect.css and bootstrap-multiselect.js files.

I have two dropdown lists with checkboxes. The first dropdown is static and depending upon the value of this the second dropdown will be populated. The first dropdown is working fine but when the second is populating, no items are being shown. The controller is returning the required list.

I have written the following jQuery to get value from controller:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "/Discount/GetProduct",
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  data: 'strId=' + message,
  success: function(data) {
    var s = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      //alert(data[i].id);
      s += '<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].value + '</option>';
    }
    $("#BrandId").html(s);
  }
```

From Chrome developers tools I find something like `class="jqmsLoaded" "style="display: none;"` for the second dropdown. If I eliminate `style="display: none;"` then all elements are showing but checkbox and other things are missing, i.e, style is distorted.

Any clues?

Comment: We need a more complete example of the problem, including the HTML and CSS, in order to debug this. It sounds like a CSS problem though, nothing to do with your JS

Comment: Yes. I am not sure which class I should add.

Comment: Also note that if you're trying to put checkboxes in a standard `select` control, then that is not going to work.

Comment: Can you share `GetProduct`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use **`.multiselect('rebuild')`** method of multiselect after you use **.append()**.

**So, modify this part of your Ajax this way:**

```
success: function(data) {

    for (var i = 0; i != data.length; i++) 
    {
        $('select#BrandId').append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].value + '</option>');
    }

    $('select#BrandId').multiselect('rebuild');

}
```

> `multiselect('rebuild')` Rebuilds the whole dropdown menu. All selected options will remain selected (if still existent!).

Comment: I have tried but not working. Data is populating in the second DDL when I commented out  the following line - $(function () {
        $('#BrandId').multiselect({
            columns: 1,
            placeholder: 'Select Brand',
            search: true,
            selectAll: true
        });
    });

Comment: I tested, and managed to build and run the code successfully. share your full javascript to consider it for you.

Comment: I have already shared javascript. Controller is sending the data and is appending in the DDL but not showing. When I add $("#BrandId").css("display", "block"); then only data is showing but without checkboxes and search option. I am using Carbon Master boot strap template. I am not sure whether the template is responsible or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample code below..

```html
 <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css">
  </head>
 
  <body>
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
 <strong>Users:</strong>
    <select id="users" multiple="multiple">
    </select>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type='button' value='Append users' onclick='loadUsers();' /></div>
<div class="col-md-4"><input type='button' value='Append Posts' onclick='loadPosts();' /></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
loadUsers();
})
function loadUsers()
{
$.ajax({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users",
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  
  success: function(data) {
 $('#users').empty();
    $('#users').multiselect('destroy')
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     $('#users').append("<option value=\"" + data[i].id + "\">" +  data[i].name + "</option>");
    }
    $('select').multiselect('refresh');
  }
})

}
function loadPosts()
{
$.ajax({
  url: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts",
  type: "GET",
  cache: false,
  
  success: function(data) {
 $('#users').empty();
    $('#users').multiselect('destroy')
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
     $('#users').append("<option value=\"" + data[i].id + "\">" +  data[i].title + "</option>");
    }
    $('select').multiselect('refresh');
  }
})

}
</script>
```

If you want to append drop down every time just remove this

```
$('#users').empty();
```